# WebStorage Android equivalent api in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, application-cache, web-storage

I went through Android WebStorage class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html
and found that it provides clean ways of deleting storage used by Application Cache and and Web SQL Database api.

I want to know whether equivalent api is available in iOS, if not how can I perform same operations as provided by Android WebStorage class in iOS.

Comment: I am facing same problem, did you got the solution?

Comment: I did not do more research on it. But WebKit framework may help you.